# Crystallography Miller indices remove equivalent indices from list

Tags: c#, list, filter

I'm doing a bit of crystallographic calculation with Miller indices (hkl), i.e. integer triples (hkl) stored here in an `int[]` array. I'm using C#. I could so far if I set a maximum hmax, kmax, and lmax fill a list containing all equivalents:

```
List<int[]> milind = new List<int[]>;
int[] mindex = new int[3];
for ( int h = -hmax ; h <= hmax; h++)
{
    mindex[0] = h;
    for ( int k = -kmax ; k <= kmax; k++)
    {
        mindex[1] = k;
        for ( int l = -lmax ; l <= lmax; l++)
        {
             mindex[2] = l;
             milind.Add(mindex);
        }
    }
}
```

QUESTION: How can I remove/filter all equivalents, i.e. permutations of one set [h,k,l] using C#?

EXAMPLE: Let's say we have `[h=1,k=0,l=0]`, I want to remove/filter:
`[0,1,0]`, `[0,0,1]`, `[-1,0,0]`, `[0,-1,0]`, `[0,0,-1]` ... etc. leaving only `[0,0,1]` in the list.

If you need some more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Define a "canonical" form for your indices such as this:

- [h] is largest magnitude index,with sign +1;
- [k] is second largest magnitude index;
- [l] is remaining index
- all common factors have been factored out

Now convert all your indices to their canonical form, and eliminate them if they are a duplicate of one already found.

This form also allows for sorting of your Miller indices, speeding up searchng, etc.

I have a physics degree; I knew Miller indices couldn't get too large.  ;-)

Here is a "Canonization" procedure. It uses brute force for the factorization, but I believe that is sufficient for the problem domain; if performance is an issue that can be addressed later.

**2013-03-09: Updated to use pre-computed table of primes <= 31**

```
  public struct MillerIndex {
    public int H { get; private set; }
    public int K { get; private set; }
    public int L { get; private set; }

    public MillerIndex( int h, int k, int l) : this() {
      H = h;  K = k;  L = l;
    }
  }

  public static class MillereHandler {

    static IList<int> Primes = new List<int> {2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31};

    public static MillerIndex GetCanonical(MillerIndex mi) {
      int h, k, l, sign;
      if (Math.Abs(mi.H) > Math.Abs(mi.K) && Math.Abs(mi.H) >  Math.Abs(mi.L) ) {
        sign = Math.Sign(mi.H);
        h = mi.H;
        k = Math.Abs(mi.K) > Math.Abs(mi.L) ? mi.K : mi.L;
        l = Math.Abs(mi.K) > Math.Abs(mi.L) ? mi.L : mi.K;
      } else if (Math.Abs(mi.K) > Math.Abs(mi.H) && Math.Abs(mi.K) >  Math.Abs(mi.L) ) {
        sign = Math.Sign(mi.K);
        h = mi.K;
        k = Math.Abs(mi.H) > Math.Abs(mi.L) ? mi.H : mi.L;
        l = Math.Abs(mi.H) > Math.Abs(mi.L) ? mi.L : mi.H;
      } else {
        sign = Math.Sign(mi.L);
        h = mi.L;
        k = Math.Abs(mi.H) > Math.Abs(mi.K) ? mi.H : mi.K;
        l = Math.Abs(mi.H) > Math.Abs(mi.K) ? mi.K : mi.H;
      }

      h *= sign;  k *= sign;  l *= sign;

      foreach (var i in Primes.Where(i=> (i^2) < l) ) {
        while ( (h/i)*i == h  &&  (k/i)*i == k &&  (l/i)*i == l ) {
          h /= h/i;  k /= k/i;  l /= l/i;
        }
      }

      return new MillerIndex(h, k, l);
    }
  }
```

Comment: How can I implement this in C#? I'm quite new in the C# business.

Comment: I am running out to do some errands.  Make a stab at it and I will check back with you in 90 minutes or so.

Comment: Oh, I forget to mention that hmax, kmax, and lmax are all about 100.

Comment: Hmm, I could create new Miller indices by invoking e.g. MillerIndex mi = new MillerIndex(1,0,0); but how would that integrate in my loop? At the moment, however, I could not figure this out.

Comment: I got you started, by showing a way to sore MillerIndices and convert them to a Canonical form. Now you still need to write a loop to run them, identify duplicates on the canonical form, and store the unique possibilities.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll try to include it.

Comment: I included it in my loop using a small modification such that and int[] array gets parsed and returned. The returned value is added to a list<int[]>. The array bounds are hmax=kmax=lmax=65. However, the actual performance is very poor. I aborted after having waited for some min.

Comment: @user2143695: You just mentioned a really important fact. I have been assuming that you had a small exisitng set of Miller indices and wanted to eliminate duplicates; but you want to find ALL unique Miller indices up to 65/65/65. That's a lot of number crunching, and a better algorithm is requred. For that many elements a table of primes is definitely worthwhile, for one, in finding common factors. Also, a feasibliity of doing the calcs on a GPU should be performed, because the algorithm looks highly parallel a priori.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to add to Pieter's answer. It is not correct to cancel out common factors. A (200) reflection is different from a (100) one. So all the effort with prime numbers is not necessary.

If you have cubic symmetry, the easiest way to generate the canonical form would be to make all indices positive by taking the absolute value and then sorting the three numbers. Thus `[0,-2,-1]` -> `[0,2,1]` -> `[0,1,2]`